# Problem running react-native app on M1 mac chip,

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I am trying to run a simple AwesomeProject on a Mac with M1 chip. I used to run the same program no problem but recently (not sure the reason is updating the macOs version or Xcode) the following error pops up each time I try to run.

```
 npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing dependencies
error Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
npm ERR! code E409
npm ERR! 409 Conflict - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@jest%2fcore

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/omid/.npm/_logs/2023-12-15T21_47_52_054Z-debug-0.log.
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
npm ERR! code E409
npm ERR! 409 Conflict - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@jest%2fcore

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/omid/.npm/_logs/2023-12-15T21_47_52_054Z-debug-0.log
    at makeError (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async installDependencies (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:206:3)
    at async createFromTemplate (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:164:7)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:327:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/omid/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:116:9)
```

Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: The term "used to" could be a very broad range of time. Did you try just using an older version of RN? The version the example of the project you're trying to run uses, or dig and find the version of RN compared to "latest" when the project you're running last had a release or commits?

Comment: Which npm version are you using ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl if it matters currently I am using 10.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Rubby I followed the instruction here and it is working now,
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#start-here-if-you-choose-the-long-and-manual-route